# bootstrap v3 css issue with dropdown in smartphones

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The site I'm working on works fine in a desktop and tablet, but the hamburger nav version in my iPhone doesn't open the sub menus. It just closes the nav when the item is selected.

I localized the culprit tag. When I remove the class 'mbr-navbar__menu', the dropdown does work, but it's visible and misaligned.

Here is the css in question:

```css
.mbr-navbar__menu-box {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.mbr-navbar__menu-box--inline-left,
.mbr-navbar__menu-box--inline-center,
.mbr-navbar__menu-box--inline-right {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.mbr-navbar__menu-box--inline-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.mbr-navbar__menu-box--inline-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

[Here is the test page I'm working on.](http://www.gallantrywebdesign.com/CIL/index_testing.html)

I hope this is enough information. Basically, I just want the dropdowns to work, with the styling that the 'mbr-navbar__menu' class provides.

Answer (score 0):

For hamburgers to work, you need to have this part, especially the `icon-bar` part:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
```

Refer to here for more info
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Thanks. The hamburger works, It's just the top level menu items aren't clickable and the submenus aren't dropping down.

Comment: Your CSS is messed up. `:after` look for this in the Chrome developer option in mobile mode. You find this after the dropdown in Bootstrap's website but in your case, is before the dropdown.